# JavaScript submit not working for action on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

I'm just trying to submit my form using JavaScript. I've broken it down into this basic function:

```
$(btnSubmit).click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $('.form')[0].submit();
    });
```

This is the form (the page name is upcoming_albums.php):

```
<form class="form" action="upcoming_albums.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

All it does is refresh the page. The form does not get submitted.

Comment: Anything in the JS console? Have you confirmed the selector in the console?

Comment: console.log( $('.form')[0]) shows me the form.

Comment: What evidence do you have it's not being submitted? If it's refreshing the page it sure sounds like it's being submitted, otherwise nothing would happen.

Comment: My evidence is that on the same screen I should see an album has been created. I see it when I don't use this JavaScript code, but when I try this it doesn't work properly. I'm using php for the normal form handling.

Comment: You sure the error isn't on the server side? If the page is refreshing then the submit is almost certainly happening.

Comment: I believe it could be due to php code. I check to see "if (isset($_POST['btn_submit'])) {" before handling submission tasks. I guess that button technically isn't set when using the JavaScript method. I'll have to think of an easy solution for this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a problem with your selector, For submitting form using JavaScript it best practice to use the form name or the unique ID, because there maybe a same class name used other places.
So, try the following code,

```
<form class="form" id="myform" action="upcoming_albums.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
```

Now, javascript will be something like

```
$(btnSubmit).click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#myform').submit();
});
```

Also please check your console for any other js error, this might help,
Thanks,

Comment: no errors in console. This didn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: Try to alert into the function, try this  $(btnSubmit).click(function(event){
    alert('yes');
    $('#myform').submit();
});

Comment: Jordan this should work, let try one another trick , give a name to you form i.e. name="theForm" and replace this jquery code document.theForm.submit();

Comment: This may be the issue. In upcoming_albums.php I use "if (isset($_POST['btn_submit'])) {" before doing any submission. I suppose that button isn't really set using this method. Removing this line is bad, though, because then the form submits on page refresh and it gets out of hand. Currently trying to think of an easy solution, rather than going to a new page.

Comment: If your page refresh , this mean you form submit event is working fine.

Comment: It could be working fine, but without setting that button, it won't actually do anything. That's just the way I have it set up.

Comment: ok Jordan , so for that you can use any hidden field and use them for condition instead of button. <input type="hidden" name="myhidden" value="formsubmit" />
Now instead of  "if (isset($_POST['btn_submit'])) {" try  "if (isset($_POST['myhidden'])) {" this will work .

Comment: I'll try this tomorrow and let you know. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much. I selected your answer as the best, but please consider adding some of your comments into the answer so it's more accessible to readers.